# Undefined control sequence at definition

Tags: expansion, expl3

Why would I be getting an error that the control sequence is undefined while I'm trying to define it?

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> * \cs_set:Nn \obj_this:n 
>                                     {\prop_item:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {##1}}\obj_t...
> ```

```
\nonstopmode \input expl3-generic \relax \ExplSyntaxOn % -*- expl3 -*-

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\cs_new:Nn \obj_method:nnn
  {
    \cs_new:cn { #1_#2 }
      {
        \cs_set:Nn \obj_this:n
          { \prop_item:Nn ##1 {####1} }
        #3
      }
  }

\prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop { key } { value }

\obj_method:nnn { sean } { get:Nn }
  { \obj_this:n {#2} }

\exp_args:No \msg_term:n { \sean_get:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { key } }

\bye
```

#### Log

```
*************************************************
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> * \cs_set:Nn \obj_this:n 
                                    {\prop_item:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {##1}}\obj_t...

\__iow_wrap_set:Nx #1#2->\cs_set_nopar:Npx #1{#2
                                                }
\iow_wrap:nnnN ...wrap_set:Nx \l__iow_wrap_tl {#1}
                                                  \tl_set:Nx \l__iow_newline...

\msg_term:n ..._wrap:nnnN {* #1}{* }{}\iow_term:n 
                                                  \iow_term:n {*************...
l.20 ...rm:n { \sean_get:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { key } }

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...m:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {##1}}\obj_this:n 
                                                  {key}
\__iow_wrap_set:Nx #1#2->\cs_set_nopar:Npx #1{#2
                                                }
\iow_wrap:nnnN ...wrap_set:Nx \l__iow_wrap_tl {#1}
                                                  \tl_set:Nx \l__iow_newline...

\msg_term:n ..._wrap:nnnN {* #1}{* }{}\iow_term:n 
                                                  \iow_term:n {*************...
l.20 ...rm:n { \sean_get:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { key } }

* \cs_set:Nn {}{key}
*************************************************
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you comment out

```
\exp_args:No \msg_term:n { \sean_get:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { key } }
```

you'll see that the error isn't from the definition, but from the fact that the argument to `\msg_term:n` isn't fully expandable. If you change that line to

```
\exp_args:No \tl_show:n { \sean_get:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { key } }
```

you get:

```
> \cs_set:Nn \obj_this:n {\prop_item:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {##1}}\obj_this:n {key}
```

which is where the error is coming from.

The `o`-expansion literally means "expand once", and in the context of a multi-token argument it refers only to the first token. In short, it just won't work here `:)`

If you run simply

```
\sean_get:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { key }
```

it will indeed typeset `value`, but you can't directly access that without doing more assignment in your code; something like:

```
\cs_new:Nn \obj_method:nnn
  {
    \cs_new:cn { #1_#2 }
      {
        \cs_set:Nn \obj_this:n
          { \prop_get:NnN ##1 {####1} ##3 }
        #3
      }
  }

\prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop { key } { value }
\obj_method:nnn { sean } { get:NnN } { \obj_this:n {#2} }

\sean_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop { key } \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
```

But I have no idea if that makes any sense for your intended application!

Comment: Was just writing much the same. You get a LaTeX3 error if you make the set up properly protected and remove the spurious `\exp_args:No` leaving the rest of that line intact.

Comment: The 'intended application' is a bit wordy for this site, but this works for me! Thanks!